# Most Efficient way to implement search and form submit with Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I've got an express app that looks up information from a database for a few topics based on "Job Number". For example, if you want to see the hours logged to a job, the route is

`.get('/hours/:jobNumber', ...)`

To get general job infoemation and details, the route is

`.get('/info/:jobNumber', ...)`

If a user navigates to just `/info` I want to show them a really basic form with a single input for Job Number and a Submit button. All that the form needs to do is essentially append `/JobNumberEntered` to the url. I've done this a couple different ways, namely:

Make it a form that posts to own URL and do something like

```
.post('/info', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/info/' + req.body.jobNumber)
})
```

I could use JS to listen for the form submit/button press and do a JS redirect to 
`/info/+document.querySelector('#jobNumber').value`

They both work... but is there a way that makes the most sense, is more faster, a "best practice" for this type of routing?

Comment: I would use the first because it is more clear to leave your routes logic in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the `post` request, it's much cleaner, avoids unnecessary client side code (allows your route to be accessible via `curl` for example) and also allows you to do some validation on that `jobNumber`.